# Permissão de usuário em tabelas Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Há uma forma de saber quais as tabelas que um determinado usuário do banco Oracle tem permissão de select?

Comment: Acessando como DBA/SYS ou como o próprio usuário?

Comment: Qual seria o comando ? Como o próprio usuário não me interessa muito, pois o intuito é de se houver uma forma, usar como auditoria. Algum usuário pode ter recebido permissão em alguma tabela há tempos e hoje pode não ser mais necessário ou não mais permitido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acessando como DBA/SYS:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_tab_privs dtp
 WHERE dtp.privilege = 'SELECT'
   AND dtp.GRANTEE   = 'USER' -- Usuário para quem o acesso foi concedido
```

Comment: Ótimo David. Isso que buscava. Obrigado!